# Python date format jan 1,2012 - jan 31,2012

Tags: python, date

I want to display the dates in the format  jan 1,2012 - jan 31,2012 
 and obtain a list consisting of dateranges['jan 1,2012 - jan 31,2012','December 1,2011 -        December 31,2011','November 1,2011 - November 3o,2011'...'February 1,2011 - February 28,2011']

i.e all the 12 months prior to present month.
 Any Ideas???
 Please help!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using the [datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) and [calendar](http://docs.python.org/library/calendar.html) modules:

```
import calendar
import datetime

current = datetime.date.today().replace(day=1)
mylist = list()
for i in xrange(12):
    rng = calendar.monthrange(current.year, current.month)
    last = current.replace(day = rng[1])
    mylist.append(current.strftime("%b 1, %Y") + " - " + last.strftime("%b %d, %Y"))
    current = (current - datetime.timedelta(1)).replace(day=1)
print mylist
```

When I run this it prints:

```
['Jan 1, 2012 - Jan 31, 2012', 'Dec 1, 2011 - Dec 31, 2011', 'Nov 1, 2011 - Nov 30, 2011', 'Oct 1, 2011 - Oct 31, 2011', 'Sep 1, 2011 - Sep 30, 2011', 'Aug 1, 2011 - Aug 31, 2011', 'Jul 1, 2011 - Jul 31, 2011', 'Jun 1, 2011 - Jun 30, 2011', 'May 1, 2011 - May 31, 2011', 'Apr 1, 2011 - Apr 30, 2011', 'Mar 1, 2011 - Mar 31, 2011', 'Feb 1, 2011 - Feb 28, 2011']
```

Comment: nice, I hadn't seen the calendar.monthrange method before. +1

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack, but hopefully someone can show you a better way:

Since there aren't that many days in the period, you could produce all the dates by brute force:

```
import datetime
for year in range(2011,2013):
    for month in range(1,13):
        for day in range(28,32):
            try:
                _date=datetime.date(year,month,day)
            except ValueError:
                print month,day

output:
2 29
2 30
2 31
4 31
6 31
9 31
11 31
2 30
2 31
4 31
6 31
9 31
11 31
```

basically using this brute force method you can work out the maximum date of each month.

I suggest:
using such a technique, create a list of date objects that represent the maximum date of each month.

create a list of date objects for the first day of each month.

sort the two lists

zip the two lists

for each pair you obtain from the zipped lists, print your date range using the strftime method

e.g.:

```
>>> datetime.date.today().strftime("%a")
'Fri'
```

If you look at http://docs.python.org/library/time.html halfway down the page it tells you what to pass strftime to get the format you want. "%a" is an example

Comment: Is this enough for you to go by? or do you want me to refine my answer?